Is there any way to have two files include eachother?
player.h in class Player
void update(TileManager tileM);
tileManager.h in class TileManager
void loadMap(int type, Player* player);
The player class only ever reads TileManager while TileManager writes to the Player class. They're both in different .cpp files.
I understand why both of these classes can't include each other. I'm just wondering if there's any way around it.

I'm just wondering if there's any way around it. -- Yes, it's called forward declaration and you want to pass tileM by reference, not by value.

From what you show tileManager.h certainly does not need to include player.h all you need is class Player; before  class TileManager { ... }; and void update(TileManager tileM); probably should be void update(const TileManager & tileM); removing the need for player.h to include TileManager.h

Both of these classes use each others logic. The player class only ever reads TileManager while TileManager writes to the Player class. -- Isn't this "logic" in separate .cpp files?  You don't have, for example, TileManager.cpp and Player.cpp?

No, they're both in different .cpp files and linked together when compiled.

and linked together when compiled -- Compilation and linking are two separate things.  You mean that each .cpp file is compiled.  Then the linker links the object code that was produced by the compilation.   Inside of Player.cpp, you would include TileManager.h, and inside of TileManager.cpp, you would include Player.h.

Yes.  (1)  Use declaration, e.g. class Player.   AND (2)   Pass the argument by pointer or reference  e.g.  loadMap(int type, Player *player).    If both headers include each other, you will need to employ include guards.    Bear in mind that defining (i.e. implementing) the functions (particularly when dereferencing a pointer, or accessing members of an object passed by reference) will need to include both headers (as the complete definition of both classes needs to be visible to the compiler).   Passing an object by value void update(TileManager tileM) requires the class to be defined.

There is another option, a design pattern called dependency inversion. Start with a new header file that only has some abstract baseclasses (interfaces). E.g. ITileManagerMethodsForPlayer and IPlayerForTileManager (both with virtual methods the classes can use on each other). After that "Player.h" and "Tilemanager.h" can include that file and use or implement those interfaces. Added bonus you now have interfaces that you can use for "dependency injection" and unit testing. You really should read more on that specialy of your game is going to be big.

Thanks for commenting about this, I'll definitely read on it. I solved the issue by putting variables I would have in the player class in the tileManager class, like spawnpoint. Then accessing them from the player class.
